# what is the difference between AAC mpeg2 and AAC mpeg4 encode ? and how to extract ADTS

Tags: audio, encode, aac

I am going to making AAC mpeg4/mpeg2 encoder

I found that AAC mpeg4 and AAC mpeg2 encode are different at "MPEG Version" in ADTS

https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=ADTS

Are there any other different between AAC mpeg4/mpeg2?

Are there any free tools to analysis aac data?
I found this one but it's not free
http://www.jongbel.com/manual-analysis/aac-audio-es-viewer/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As for difference between AAC MPEG4/MPEG2, please see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding

As for the free tools, you may use FAAD open source in github:
https://github.com/dsvensson/faad2

It can parse raw AAC MPEG4/MPEG2 and data in MP4.